# Weird error appearing in Eclipse (Force.com IDE V31) with Cases

Tags: eclipse, error-messages

I have a line of code that for some reason shows up as a compile error even though it saves fine to server.  I get this error in different orgs as well but I can force Eclipse to save and it saves the changes even though there is an error.  Does anyone know why this error is appearing?

Code:

```
Case filenetCase = new Case(Priority = priority, OwnerId = ownerId, RecordTypeId = rTypeId, Subject = subject, Description = description, Workflow_ID__c = activityId,
           ContactId = contId, Origin = 'Internal', Reason = 'Account Open', Case_Reason_Type__c = 'Discrepency', Status = 'New');
insert filenetCase;
```

Error Message:

[image]

It does not prevent me from saving code or changing it but it's aggravating to have an error that keeps popping up each time I try to make changes to this class.

Comment: Not a fix but if you refresh the class from the server the error goes away until you open it again. At least keeps the errors panel clean.

Comment: dphil -- this would have driven me nuts -- you might want to retitle your OP as it appears this is a V31 IDE issue relating to using the Case SObject in apex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a known bug - see [Compiler Error: message = mismatched input 'case' expecting RCURLY #34](https://github.com/forcedotcom/idecore/issues/34) but AFAIK there is no official release yet containing the fix. You could be brave and use the [beta](https://github.com/forcedotcom/idecore/wiki/Downloading-the-Beta-Version-of-the-Force.com-IDE) if it became a big problem for you.

Comment: Perfect.  Going brave with the beta already installed now.  Apparently I have to wait 4 more min to accept your answer.